# Salesforce1 <apex:selectlist>

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, multi-select, selectlist

As APEX:SELECTLIST is one among the unsupported Visualforce components of Salesforce1 APP is there any other solution for the select list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden apex:inputText and add html select tag with apex:repeate for options and you will need to add JS that will fill in apex:inputText field

Comment: How to use HTML SELECT tag as a multi-select list(Multiple attribute wasn't working)?

Comment: Try to use this article from w3c http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: multiple is not accepted in VF.

Comment: try to use multiple="multiple" or if it not wors multiple="true". Also you can try to use some jquery plugins like select2 or bootstrap